# Wiring power banks in series for 25V output to power e-bike

Tags: series, 5v, mobile

So I have an old electric bike sitting around, no battery. Replacement 24V 10Ah batteries are $200+. However, I have/can get 10Ah power banks (to charge phones) for under $10. They all have standard 5V 2A outputs. Same brand and model. Bike is an ancient Ezip eco ride; 250W motor.

Can I wire 5 power packs in series to get a ~24-25V output? I can't do it via the USB ports, because I can't pass voltage back through the USB port - it overloads and shuts down.

I'm afraid of opening the power packs and wiring the batteries directly, because the PCBs are still connected and might get damaged.

Assume I disconnect the PCBs from the batteries before wiring them in series. Also assume I time the battery usage so they don't over-discharge. What's the chance this will go up in flames, Note 7 style?

If you're gonna call me an idiot for even suggesting this, please do so kindly. Thanks! ^_^

Comment: You really should consider using a 6SxP LiFePO4 battery instead, with appropriate charger.

Comment: It is not enough to check only the capacity and voltage rating of batteries, when searching for replacements.
You should also check maximum discharge current rating too for example. If it is a 250 W motor, on 24 V it should draw more than 10 A. I think those power banks unable to support that much current.

Comment: *10Ah power banks (to charge phones) for under $10* Beware that these cheap powerbanks often use inferior cells, so the real capacity will be much lower and they will **NOT** be suited for high discharge currents like needed for a bike. Just forget about using these powerbanks I guarantee you that they're a waste of money for this purpose. There is a reason that the original battery is so expensive, good quality cells that can handle high discharge currents simply are expensive. There is no way around that.

Comment: You can wire them in series to get 25 V but the current will still be only 2 A in the best case scenario which is less than the 10 A needed to drive the motor. It will not work.

Comment: If you disconnect the PCBs from the batteries, they won't output 5V 2A anymore. That's the output *of* *the* *PCB*.

Answer (score 12):

Your power banks provide 5V 2A output or 10W, and cost about $10. To power a 250W motor, you'll need 25 power banks which will cost you $250. Why not just buy a $200 battery then?

Also, think how bulky those 25 power banks will be on your bike, and what a pain they will be to charge.

Hopefully these simple arguments are enough to persuade you, before I'll have to explain all the balancing issues you'll face once you connect Li-ion cells in series, or consider custom charging circuits you'll need to design if you remove the original PCBs.

Comment: Could you explain why 25 power banks?

Comment: @Uwe 250W / 10W = 25

Comment: In other words you would need 5 parallel chains of powerbanks to supply 10A. And that ignores the problem that you'll need much more than 10A while starting.

Comment: @BrianDrummond On e-bikes, batteries are typically connected to a power control unit which generates AC current for the motor and acts as a buck converter at startup, limiting both voltage and current.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'd say the OP will have more troubles balancing those power banks if he decides to use them. Without balancing, I wouldn't risk discharging them by more than 30-50%.

Comment: His plan is utterly impractical, but this answer misses the fact that he plans to remove the PCBs. So the output of each power bank won't have any special relationship to the 10W output of the PCB circuit.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz short of a datasheet for the cells I have to assume they can provide the same 10W with PCBs removed. And I didn't address issues arising from removing the PCBs on purpose, since the plan is impractical even before such issues are considered.

Comment: It's much more likely to be between 18W and 40W, depending on exactly what batteries are inside. But given that they're bottom of the line power packs, your biggest problem will be keeping enough cells working at once to get the whole thing to work.